# What's the difference between ModelA.transaction do ..end and ModelB.transaction do ..end in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, transactions

I have two models(ActiveRecord), ModelA and ModelB. I am wondering is the same for the two code segment show as below?

```
ModelA.transaction do 
    ModelA.create! attr1: 'value1', attr2: 'value2'
    ModelB.create! attr1: 'value1', attr2: 'value2'
end

ModelB.transaction do 
    ModelA.create! attr1: 'value1', attr2: 'value2'
    ModelB.create! attr1: 'value1', attr2: 'value2'
end
```

It seems that both of them working well. so what's the difference between them?

thanks

Comment: There is no difference, all derive the method from `ActiveRecord::Base` without any changes.

Comment: You don’t show your model code but I assume it’s standard. Where you might run into issues is if ModelA pointed at a different database than ModelB and you tried doing a single transaction for both models in one call. I don’t have that setup anywhere anymore to test, maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: thank you @AlekseiMatiushkin , you should post as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Transactions are per database connections not not per model. So both of them are equal provided class are mapped to same database.

Reference: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html